# Magento admin grid

Tags: magento, grid

Is there a way to show grid in some tab of Magento configuration?
Grid must display data from custom table.
Something, like [that](http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/574528/0398b533d63040619926ac12ba1af199)

But not to save data in *core_config table*, but in my own.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, there is a very instructive tutorial that is doing what you need:

http://www.demacmedia.com/ecommerce/enabling-linked-field-configuration-magento-module/

Comment: Thanks :), but this tutorial doing almost the same as default Magento example in my screenshot. Instead, I need to show the grid with data(more than 5 columns) from my collection (which consist of several tables) and allow some rows to be deleted by admin and save those changes to that collection(tables).

Comment: So you should load your data, and add the grids that you need, the main ideea on how to start the job...